# Can I inject javascript blocks from a child template in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a child template which extends ::base.html.twig. The base template includes a javascripts block. I can override the included javascripts inside my child template.

But then if I do an twig include to a third template which just contains a form, I cannot inject additional javascript from the third template inside the child template inside the javascripts block (or a nested block)

There is further detail here - https://gist.github.com/3182772

Is this possible?

This github issue seems to suggest that it isn't but traits are no good to me as I am extending a base template.

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/644

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381277/446594

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the inner block. Just keep doing this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {# put additional JS here #}
{% endblock %}
```

You can keep doing this for as much levels as you need.

Comment: I can't do that if my template doesn't extend or use the parent. If I try to do that, I get 'A template that extends another one cannot have a body'

Comment: You're getting this exception when you put content outside of any blocks defined in parent templates. If, for example, you extend `::base.html.twig`, you should put the content into the `body` block.